# Where can i get a list of all functions from Request Class in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I was searching and found only couple of examples, I want a manual like php.net on all functions in  Request Class in Laravel. How to find out what functions in Request Class, what functions in Model Class.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class TodosControler extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }
}

class Todo extends Model
{
    //
}
```

Comment: **Request Class:** https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/requests
**Model:**
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent

Comment: On https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/ there is only couple of examples, there is no list of functions. Where is a Manual on functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel already provides manual for all class and methods [here](https://laravel.com/api/7.x/)

For **Request** class:

https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Http/Request.html

For **Model** class:

https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html